# Python GUI using Tkinter how to print input exactly the way you enter them?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm exploring tkinter as of now and trying to do sample exercises I can think of. What I want is when I enter an input like this:

`I've
entered
this`

I want to display them that way as well but I'm only getting this:

`I'veenteredthis`

This is a snippet from my code for this part:

`input = textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
 logBox.insert(tk.END, input)`

I've tried doing these:
`input = input.replace("\n", "\n")`, `logBox.insert(tk.END, input+ "\n")`

Please do understand that I'm not well equipped with knowledge in Python as I am still trying to learn the language. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Here is the full code just don't mind the other parts since I'm trying to do something

````
import sys
import os
import time
import operator
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def test():
    input = textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    # input = input.replace("\n", "\n")
    logBox.insert(tk.END, input+ "\n")

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(window.winfo_screenwidth(), 
window.winfo_screenheight()))
window.title("Test")

mainFrame = Frame(window, width=8000, height=8000)
mainFrame.pack(side=TOP)

LabelText = Label(mainFrame, text="Type your text below:", anchor='center', pady=10)
LabelText.pack()

textBox = tk.Text (mainFrame, font=('averdana', 10), height=18, width=180)
textBox.pack()

BTNRun = Button(mainFrame, text="Run", height=1, width=10, 
command=test)
BTNRun.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

LogText = Label(mainFrame, text="Console Log", anchor='ne', pady=10)
LogText.pack()

logBox = tk.Listbox(mainFrame, font=('averdana', 10), height=10, width=180)
logBox.pack()


BTNExit = Button(mainFrame, text="Exit", height=1, width=10, command=quit)
BTNExit.pack()

window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Please give your full code

Comment: Probably not the main issue here, but you should avoid using input as a variable name in Python 3 given that it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need to see what type of object `logBox` and `textBox` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not name a variable input. `input` is a built in method of python. That said you need to split the string at the line breaks so use `split()` and then input the resulting list.

Change this:

```
def test():
    input = textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    # input = input.replace("\n", "\n")
    logBox.insert(tk.END, input+ "\n")
```

To this:

```
# had to update this function my original answer had some issues
def test():
    my_input = textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    x = my_input.split("\n")
    for item in x:
        logBox.insert(tk.END, item.strip())
```

Comment: What's missing is the last part. Thank you!